# como puedo guardar un insert en un txt

Tags: c#, sql-server

tengo un problema no logro guardar u insert completo en un txt, me lo guarda pero me guarda los parametros no los valores reales, este es mi codigo

```
 if (!dao.success) throw new Exception(dao.message);

        //Leer metadatos: Tabla y Campos

        string insert = String.Empty;
        string param = String.Empty;
        string tableName = String.Empty;
        string nombreTable = String.Empty;
        string delete = String.Empty;
        object value = null;
        //DateTime fecha;
        //fecha = DateTime.Now;
        string fecha = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");

        List<Tuple<string, int, object>> tuplas = null;

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {


            if (!tableName.Equals(row["TableName"].ToString(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(tableName))
                {

                    //Guardar datos en las listas

                    insert = insert.Substring(0, insert.Length - 1) + ") ";
                    param = param.Substring(0, param.Length - 1) + ")";
                    select = select.Substring(0, select.Length - 1) + " FROM " + tableName + " WHERE FECHA_MODIFICACION <=" + "'" + fecha + "'";
                    inserts.Add(insert + param);
                    selects.Add(select);
                    deletes.Add(delete);
                    nombreTables.Add(nombreTable);
                    dao.respaldoRegistrosLog(inserts, selects, tableName, fecha);
                    tableName = String.Empty;

                }

                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(tableName))
                {
                    tableName = row["TableName"].ToString();
                    tuplas = new List<Tuple<string, int, object>>();

                    //List<object> value = new List<object>(); //OBTENER LISTA DE LOG (Registros)

                    insert = "INSERT INTO " + tableName + " ("; //generaSQL(tableName, tuplas);
                    param = "VALUES (";
                    select = "SELECT ";
                    delete = "DELETE FROM " + tableName + " WHERE FECHA_MODIFICACION <=" + "'" + fecha + "'";
                    nombreTable = "SELECT a.name FROM sys.objects AS a WHERE a.type = 'U' AND a.name LIKE '%_LOG' ORDER BY a.name";
                }
            }



            insert += row["ColumnName"].ToString() + ",";
            select += row["ColumnName"].ToString() + ",";
            param += "@P" + row["ColumnOrder"].ToString() + ",";
            //int columnorder = Convert.ToInt32(row["ColumnOrder"]) - 1;

        }
```

en esta parte del codigo armo el insert con los parametros

y en este otro codigo se supone que debería guardarlo en el txt.

```
origen = new SqlConnection(conexionOrigen);

                    int a = 0;
                    string respaldoLog = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["rutaRespaldoArchivo"];
                    string rutaCompleta = respaldoLog + "/" + tableName + "_" + fecha + ".txt";


                    foreach (DataRow row in db.Rows)
                    {
                        byte loop = 0;

                        cmd = new SqlCommand(inserts[index]);
                        cmd.Connection = origen;
                        origen.Open();

                        do
                        {

                            foreach (DataColumn dc in db.Columns)
                            {
                                a++;
                                loop++;

                                using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(rutaCompleta, true))
                                {
                                    string nombreParametro = prefijoParametro + (dc.Ordinal + 1).ToString();
                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(nombreParametro, row[dc.Ordinal]);
                                    file.WriteLine(cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(nombreParametro, row[dc.Ordinal]));
                                    file.Close();
                                }

                            }


                        } while (loop < 3);



                        origen.Close();


                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

si alguien tiene alguna idea o alguna pagina para orientarme se lo agradecería.

Comment: Le recomiendo 2 cosas: 1) En una variable string escriba la sentencia SQL a ejecutar "INSERT, stored procedured, etc". y muéstrela en consola - puede que tenga errores tipográficos, 2) use try/catch para capturar los detalles del error. Mire cómo usar el [try/catch](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/how-to-use-the-try-catch-block-to-catch-exceptions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si lo que intentas escribir en tu log es la consulta que realizas en modo texto puedes hacer usar la siguiente función:

```
private static string ConvertCommandParamatersToLiteralValues(SqlCommand cmd)
{
    string query = cmd.CommandText;
    foreach (SqlParameter prm in cmd.Parameters)
    {
        switch (prm.SqlDbType)
        {
            case SqlDbType.Bit:
                    int boolToInt = (bool)prm.Value ? 1 : 0;
                    query = query.Replace(prm.ParameterName, string.Format("{0}", (bool)prm.Value ? 1 : 0));
                    break;
            case SqlDbType.Int:
                    query = query.Replace(prm.ParameterName, string.Format("{0}", prm.Value));
                    break;
            case SqlDbType.VarChar:
                    query = query.Replace(prm.ParameterName, string.Format("'{0}'", prm.Value));
                    break;
            default:
                    query = query.Replace(prm.ParameterName, string.Format("'{0}'", prm.Value));
                    break;
        }
    }
    return query;
}
```

Es posible que tengas que añadir algún `case` mas para adaptarlo a tus necesidades pero es un ejemplo de como poder hacerlo.

Un saludo y suerte

Comment: es buena la idea, pero me entrega los valores desordenado

Comment: en este punto
string nombreParametro = prefijoParametro + (dc.Ordinal + 1).ToString();
                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(nombreParametro, row[dc.Ordinal]);

entrego los valores ordenado con los parametros

Comment: Podrías añadir un ejemplo de entrada y de salida esperada a tu pregunta? Es que no acabo de entender el problema.

Comment: funciono, lo había aplicado mal, muchas gracias